# android 5 Уведомления приходит белый квадрат

Tags: android

android 5 уведомления приходит белый квадрат, на старых моделях приходит нормальная картинка. как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Что такое уведомления и что за картинка, и откуда она приходит?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/design/style/iconography.html#notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notification
изменяем версию андроида на targetSdkVersion 20 в gradle файле